# Reorder SVG elements created by RaphaelJS?

Tags: javascript, svg, raphael

Lets assume I create two Raphael elements and attach to single div element in the DOM. eg: http://jsfiddle.net/sreedharmb/ApnwB/2/

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>append demo</title>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/raphael/2.1.0/raphael-min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

    <div id="sample-1"></div>

    <script>
        var paper = Raphael("sample-1", 200, 75);
        var paper1 = Raphael("sample-1", 200, 75);
        var rect = paper.rect(10, 10, 50, 50);
        var rect1 = paper1.rect(10, 10, 50, 50);

        rect.attr({fill: "green"});
        rect1.attr({fill: "red"});    
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

In this example I expected green rectangle to plotted before red. But result seems to be different. What is the reason for this behaviour?

I checked out the output html in chrome, to my surprise SVG element of red rectangle is above green rectangle.

```
<body>
<div id="sample-1">
<svg height="75" version="1.1" width="200" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" style="overflow: hidden; position: relative;"><desc style="-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);">Created with Raphaël 2.1.0</desc><defs style="-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);"></defs><rect x="10" y="10" width="50" height="50" r="0" rx="0" ry="0" fill="#ff0000" stroke="#000" style="-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);"></rect></svg>
<svg height="75" version="1.1" width="200" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" style="overflow: hidden; position: relative;"><desc style="-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);">Created with Raphaël 2.1.0</desc><defs style="-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);"></defs><rect x="10" y="10" width="50" height="50" r="0" rx="0" ry="0" fill="#008000" stroke="#000" style="-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);"></rect></svg>
</div>

<script>
    var paper = Raphael("sample-1", 200, 75);
    var paper1 = Raphael("sample-1", 200, 75);
    var rect = paper.rect(10, 10, 50, 50);
    var rect1 = paper1.rect(10, 10, 50, 50);

    rect.attr({fill: "green"});
    rect1.attr({fill: "red"});    
</script>
</body>
```

Is there a way to reorder the SVG created by RaphaelJS or is there a way to control the behaviour of RaphaelJS while adding SVG to a div.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Raphael adds the new SVG element always as the first child element of the container. The relevant [code](https://github.com/DmitryBaranovskiy/raphael/blob/master/dev/raphael.svg.js) in Raphael is lines 1247-1251:

```
if (container.firstChild) {
    container.insertBefore(cnvs, container.firstChild);
} else {
    container.appendChild(cnvs);
}
```

The easiest "fix" is to initialize the Raphaël canvases in reverse order, so `paper1` before `paper`. You could also reorder them manually, by, for example:

```
var cont = document.getElementById("sample-1");
cont.appendChild(cont.firstChild);
```

This however *will break the connection from Raphaël to the DOM element* and thus isn't really a solution if you still need to change/add elements to it afterwards.

Finally, you could also create additional `div` elements inside you `sample-1` `div` and initialise the Raphaëls to be inside those elements.

Comment: Thanks a lot.. Temporary i initialized Raphael canvases in reverse order.